# White space on the left of vertical nav bar

Tags: css, html

I am having difficulty removing the white space to the left of my vertical nav bar.

I have tried setting padding-left to 0 on my main-bar.

It's my first time building a nav bar, so if you see something semantically wrong with my codes, do let me know as well.

Thank you!

This is the HTML code.

```
<title>Mockup of Zopim</title>
<body>
    <main>
        <nav class = "side-bar">
            <ul class ="main-bar">
                <li class="user-nav"><a class ="big-box" href="#">User</a></li>
                <li class="main-nav"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="main-nav"><a href="#">Visitor List</a></li>
                <li class="main-nav"><a href="#">Visualization</a></li>
                <li class="main-nav"><a href="#">History</a></li>
                <li class="divider-nav"><a href="#">Manage</a></li>
                <li class="manage-nav"><a href="#">Agents</a></li>
                <li class="manage-nav"><a href="#">Departments</a></li>
                <li class="manage-nav"><a href="#">Shortcuts</a></li>
                <li class="manage-nav"><a href="#">Banned Visitors</a></li>
                <li class="manage-nav"><a href="#">Triggers</a></li>
                <li class="divider-nav"><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                <li class="settings-nav"><a href="#">Widgets</a></li>
                <li class="settings-nav"><a href="#">Personal</a></li>
                <li class="settings-nav"><a href="#">Accounts</a></li>
            </ul>
       </nav>
       <article>
        <header>
            <h1>Hello!</h1>
        </header>
       </article>
    </main>
</body>
```

This is the CSS code.

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body {
    background-color: black;
}
main {
    width: 100%;
}
.side-bar {
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #585858;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
nav li {
    list-style: none;
}
.main-bar {
    padding-left: 0px;
}
.main-bar li a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
article {
    width: 60%;
    height: 30%;
    float: right;
    position: relative; 
}
a.big-box {
    display: block;
    line-height: 7em;
}
header h1 {
    color: white;
}
```

Here is the JSfiddle link.

http://jsfiddle.net/codermax/fe0L3d08/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most Web browsers have different default settings for the base margins and padding. So The best way to solve this is to set all the margin and padding

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

or 
html,body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Also better if you reset your css then you can use. something like this:

http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a reset.css to resolve different browser quirks.
I've updated your sample and set body margin, and padding to 0.

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fe0L3d08/1/

Comment: Yes because one is only allowed to post jsfiddle links if also having a code tag in the post. I hope people will be able to copy and paste it into their location bar.

Comment: I thought so too, but now as you mention it, its not, I'll add a code tag in my post and link the fiddle.