# Navigation is not covering all the way

Tags: css, html

I am new to CSS. I am trying to re-create a website from case-study in the book. As you can see in the picture I attached the navigation bar leaves little space on the left. I am not able to find out what is causing this or How can I fix this?[View of the webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6vd0.png)

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
}

nav {
  letter-spacing: 0.5em;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

#dot {
  list-style-type: none;
}

body {
  background-color: #4286f4;
  text-align: center;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: small;
  font-family: italic;
}

header {
  background-color: #91b0e2;
}

main {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <h1>Nature Walk</h1>
  </header>
  <ul id="dot">
    <nav>
      <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
      <li><a href="Amenities.html">Amenities</a></li>
      <li><a href="eForms.html">eForms</a></li>
    </nav>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `nav` should be the parent of the `ul`, not the other way around. But `ul` generally has left padding by default unless you set it otherwise, so you can set a rule like `nav ul { padding-left: 0; }` and clear that up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [White space on the left of vertical nav bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25578126/white-space-on-the-left-of-vertical-nav-bar)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove white space on ul with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17129891/remove-white-space-on-ul-with-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to update one class which is #dot
Whenever used ul by default it has padding at left side so you need to update using padding:0 or padding-left:0

```
#dot{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding:0;
}
```